# String operation in PHP

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I'm now dealing with uri like /page.html?k1=1&k2=2

```
$str = preg_replace('/[&\?]' . $k . '=[^&]*/',"",$str);
```

The above aims to delete $k related part in uri,but will also  delete ? wrongly.

How to do the right thing?

Comment: I'm confused - please clarify what you want the resulting string to look like after the regex has been applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/(?:(\?)|&)' . $k . '=[^&]*/', '$1', $str)
```

You should additionally use [`preg_quote`](http://docs.php.net/preg_quote) on `$k`.

**Edit**    Here’s an extended version of the above that should fix the problem described by beggs:

```
/(?:(\?)|&)arg=[^&]*(?(1)(?:&|$))/
```

The `(?(1)(?:&|$))` epxression is a [conditional expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) that is used if the first group found a match. So if `?` is found, the trailing `&` of that parameter is removed.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a portion of a querystring, I would not use regular expressions, but functions that exist to manipulate URLs.

For instance, considering this portion of code, which uses the [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) function to extract parts of an URL :

```
$url = '/page.html?k1=1&k2=2';
$parts = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parts);
```

You'll get :

```
array
  'path' => string '/page.html' (length=10)
  'query' => string 'k1=1&k2=2' (length=9)
```

You can now extract the informations contained in the original query string, with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) :

```
$params = array();
parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Which will get you :

```
array
  'k1' => string '1' (length=1)
  'k2' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Now, to remove one parameter, you can test if it exists in the array, and, if yes, remove it :

```
$to_remove = 'k1';
if (array_key_exists($to_remove, $params)) {
    unset($params[$to_remove]);
}
var_dump($params);
```

Which now gives the following array of parameters :

```
array
  'k2' => string '2' (length=1)
```

And, finally, you can put back the pieces together, using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) :

```
$new_query = http_build_query($params);
var_dump($new_query);
```

And you get :

```
string 'k2=2' (length=4)
```

You now just have to inject this after your URL ;-)

Some might say it's a bit longer... I would answer that, looking at this code, one immediatly inderstands its purpose -- which is not quite the case with a complex regex.

Answer (score 1):

It's deleting the "`?`" because you have included it in the match and are using an empty replace.  To remove the variable matching "`$k`" and leave the "`?`" use the code Gumbo provided, but be aware that when "`$k`" == "`k1`" the result string will be "`/page.html?&k2=2`", note the left over "`&`".

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with URLs and query strings, you might want to use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract URL components and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to extract query string bits.  It'll be much easier to manipulate an array of arguments instead of dealing with regexes.  You can then use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to put it back together again.